# Android FloatingActionMenu not showing labels

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to implement a Floating Button Action using `this framework`. My problem is that the items of the menu have the same size of the main button, even using "mini" and the text of the labels don't show. Image bellow:
[image]

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/material_design_android_floating_action_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#da3c2f"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
        fab:menu_fab_label="Floating Action Menu"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 1"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star_half_empty"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 2"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 3"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm having a hard time to figure out what I'm missing to make it work [like this](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/screenshots/menu_down_opened.png?raw=true)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Notice the change in  **xmlns:fab**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried what you said but then the app wouldn't compile. I had to change fab: for app: